# Why firebase storage object.resourceState of onFinalize returning undefined?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

According to firebase docs on cloud functions, object.resourceState should have value either 'exists' or 'not-exists'. Strangely, in my case it is returning undefined.

Here is my code :

```
exports.onUpload = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object, context) => {

console.log(object.resourceState);
});
```

Comment: If you are certain this is not behaving according to the documentation, then file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I assumed i may be doing something wrong and may be someone can point out. Anyway, i filled the bug. Lets see. Thanks for taking the time to suggest.